# Python Regex, optional word in brackets?

Tags: python, regex

I have a quick question on regex, I have a certain string to match. It is shown below:

```
"[someword] This Is My Name 2010"
or
"This Is My Name 2010"
or
"(someword) This Is My Name 2010"
```

Basically if given any of the strings above, I want to only keep "This Is My Name" and "2010".

What I have now, which I will use result = re.search and then result.group() to get the answer:

```
'[\]\)]? (.+) ([0-9]{4})\D'
```

Basically it works with the first and third case, by allowing me to optionally match the end bracket, have a space character, and then match "This Is My Name".

However, with the second case, it only matches "Is My Name". I think this is because of the space between the '?' and '(.+)'.

Is there a way to deal with this issue in pure regex?

One way I can think of is to add an "if" statement to determine if the word starts with a [ or ( before using the appropriate regex.

Comment: You can omit the `\D` at the end `[])]? (.+) ([0-9]{4})` https://regex101.com/r/p4n1jv/1 and make it for example a word boundary `[])]? (.+) ([0-9]{4})\b`

Comment: Could [this](https://regex101.com/r/xbtFP1/2) be helpfull? Is your string always the exact same pattern?

Comment: @JvdV Yes it works! thank you for the help! below there is another answer which requires some pre-processing which works too. Yup its always the same pattern, or at least I will try to keep it that way.

Comment: So you could also get away with something like: `re.split(r'\]|\)', text)[-1].strip().rsplit(" ",1)`?

Comment: @JvdV Yep looks like I can! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern that you tried `[\]\)]? (.+) ([0-9]{4})\D` optionally matches a closing square bracket or parenthesis. Adding the `\D` at the end, it ***expects*** to match any character that is not a digit.

---

You can optionally match the `(...)` or `[...]` part before the first capturing group, as `[])]` only matches the optional closing one.

Then you can capture all that follows in group 1, followed by matching the last 4 digits in group 2 and add a word boundary.

```
(?:\([^()\n]*\) |\[[^][\n]*\] )?(.+) ([0-9]{4})\b
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `([^()\n]*)`  Match either `(...)` and space
  - `|` Or
  - `[[^][\n]*]`  `[...]` and space
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `(.+)`  Capture **group 1**, Match 1+ times any char except a newline followed by a space
- `([0-9]{4})\b` Capture **group 2**, match 4 digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VH38k4/1)

Note that `.*` will match until the end of the line and then backtracks until the last occurrence of 4 digits. If that should be the first occurrence, you could make it non greedy `.*?`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace the first portion of the sentence if it starts with (square or round) brackets, with an empty string. No `if` statement is needed:

```
import re

s1 = "[someword] This Is My Name 2010"
s2 = "This Is My Name 2010"
s3 = "(someword) This Is My Name 2010"

reg = '\[.*?\] |\(.*?\) '

res1 = re.sub(reg, '', s1)
print(res1)

res2 = re.sub(reg, '', s2)
print(res2)

res3 = re.sub(reg, '', s3)
print(res3)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
This Is My Name 2010
This Is My Name 2010
This Is My Name 2010
```